# How can I modify the horizontal space that my figures can fill?

Tags: spacing, subfloats, sidewaysfigure

I am entering a triple-figure like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.72\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.72\textwidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass1.png}
        \caption{$M\in (3, 4]\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.72\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.72\textwidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass2.png}
        \caption{$M\in (4, 5]\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.72\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=0.72\textwidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass3.png}
        \caption{$M>5\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Derivatives of the tangential shear profiles with respect to the matter fluctuation parameter.}
\end{figure}

\end{document
```

Here is what comes out: 
[image]

As you can see, the label on the y-axis is cut off. How can I modify the code to widen the horizontal scope that is allowed?

Comment: @Bobyandbob What is MWE? and what is a tikz code?

Comment: And I don't know what you mean by "The original images .PNG are okay?"... what do you mean are they okay?

Comment: (i) with `fbox{ \includegraphics[width=0.72\textwidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass1.png}}` look, if around your image is white space. If it is, remuve them with `trim` option in `\includegraphics` or better in program, which is image source (this is test, if your images are OK :)); (ii) increase width of image with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]`.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, maybe post as an answer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. See how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

We haven't data/information about your images nor Minimal Working Example (MWE), by which we can search for cause of your problem. Based on guessing:

- Maybe your images has white space around it. To see, if this is a case, make the with including your images in `\fbox{...}`, for example:

`\fbox{ \includegraphics[width=0.72\textwidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents‌​/FINALVALUES/Plots/D‌​erivatives/mass1.png‌​}}`

If you will see white space around image, you can remove it with `trim` option  `\includegraphics[trim= ...]`  or better in program by which images are generated [this is test, if your images are OK :)]

- increase image size with enlarge image width with

`\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`

- from your code snipped can be concluded, that **you like to have all images in one line**, but you set sub-figure width equal to `0.7\textwidth`. Consequently image cannot be placed in one row ... this make your question even more confusing:

Test of your code snipped `demo` option of `graphicx` package with two selection of images width gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
Images are in one row:
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass1.png}
        \caption{$M\in (3, 4]\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass2.png}
        \caption{$M\in (4, 5]\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass3.png}
        \caption{$M>5\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Derivatives of the tangential shear profiles with respect to the matter fluctuation parameter.}
\end{figure}

Images are spread over three rows:
\begin{figure}[!hb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.2\linewidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass1.png}
        \caption{$M\in (3, 4]\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.2\linewidth] {/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass2.png}
        \caption{$M\in (4, 5]\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.2\linewidth]{/Users/Olly/Documents/FINALVALUES/Plots/Derivatives/mass3.png}
        \caption{$M>5\times 10^{14}$Msol/h}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Derivatives of the tangential shear profiles with respect to the matter fluctuation parameter.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Red frame (produced by package `showframe`) show page layout. In real document it had to be removed.

Comment: I have provided an MWE now. I have tried your suggestions but the label on the y-axis is still being cut off. The label on the x-axis also gets cut off if I make the text larger.

Comment: I have also tried to make the margin size smaller, but this doesn't work.

Comment: @ODP, than you have problem with images. please. provide images somewhere where I can download them.

Comment: @ODP, any news?